# populate html table with jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have table and i want to append data in the middle of table through jquery.

### here is my table code html

```
  <table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
```

**here i need to append tr with jQuery**

```
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

is it possible with jquery? if so then please guide me.
if i can populate then i can do like

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            $("#NamesGridView").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].FirstName + 
                                     "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Age + "</td></tr>");
         }
       }
```

please guide thanks

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: 305 questions even.. lol

Comment: looks like you use SO only to get your questions answered..

Comment: this is much better  than ppl creating random accts for every question right..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Edit** Based on comment:

```
$('#thetable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
var html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)
            html += '<tr><td>' + data.d[i].FirstName + 
                    '</td><td>' + data.d[i].Age + '</td></tr>';
$('#thetable tr').first().after(html);
```

Example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/FXJrG/)

Comment: He just wants to insert it after the first row, which already exists. So it being inserted at the end works perfectly unless there are other rows in the table to begin with, which I don't think he mentioned.

Comment: well the question shows that he needs to insert it after the header row but before the second tow.. i dnt know what more do you want him to mention..  there is **here i need to append tr with jQuery**

Comment: @zzzz, Oh, I get it. I interpreted that as him showing the tr he wanted to append after the first row, not as showing a row already in the table.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i need one guide line that how to remove all rows first except first & last tr or rows and then add many rows in between first and last rows. it think it is possible by jquery....but i am new in jquery. so please help me to do it.......thanks

Answer (score 10):

Below Code will  populate html table with jquery.

```
<table id="tablefriendsname">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

$.ajax({    
type: "POST",
url: "/users/index/friendsnamefromids",
data: "IDS="+requests,
dataType: "json", 
success: function(response){
    var name = response;
            //Important code starts here to populate table  
    var yourTableHTML = "";
        jQuery.each(name, function(i,data) {
            $("#tablefriendsname").append("<tr><td>" + data + "</td></tr>");
        });
}
});
```

Comment: Why `var name = response;`? What's the advantage over working directly on `response`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are adding the data in for loop, it would be more performant to build the string first then add it all in one call.

```
var newRows = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
   newRows += "<tr><td>" + data.d[i].FirstName + 
              "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Age + "</td></tr>";
}
$("table tr:first").after(newRows);
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i need one guide line that how to remove all rows first except first & last tr or rows and then add many rows in between first and last rows. it think it is possible by jquery....but i am new in jquery. so please help me to do it.......thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$("table tr:first").after("<tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td></tr>")
```

Basically use `after()` or `before()` use the right selector

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xSxAt/1/)

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i need one guide line that how to remove all rows first except first & last tr or rows and then add many rows in between first and last rows. it think it is possible by jquery....but i am new in jquery. so please help me to do it.......thanks

Comment: $("table tr:not(:first),table tr:not(:last)").remove() or $("table tr:not(:first),table tr:not(:last)").detach()

Answer (score 2):

Add the `id NamesGridView` to the first `tr`

```
<table border="1">
<tr id="NamesGridView">
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and change the `append` to `after`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    $("#NamesGridView").after("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].FirstName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Age + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NbNk/).

Comment: That flips the data. Last row will be first etc.

Comment: That's right, but not defined in the question. To change this behaviour, the `id` has to be moved to the first `tr` before the new rows should be added and the `after` method changed to `before`.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i need one guide line that how to remove all rows first except first & last tr or rows and then add many rows in between first and last rows. it think it is possible by jquery....but i am new in jquery. so please help me to do it.......thanks