# Populating a table from JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

Is this an effective way to populate a table from with JSON data using jQuery or is there a better/less costly way? The maximum number of rows will be around 100. I'd prefer not to use a plugin.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'public.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var row = '<tr class="header">';
        for (var i in data.headers) {
            row += '<th style=""><a href="#" class="sort"><span>' + data.headers[i] + '</span></a></th>';
        }
        row += '</tr>'
        $(row).appendTo('table.data');
        row = '';
        for (var i in data.rows) {
            row += '<tr id="' + i + '">';
            row += '<td>' + data.rows[i].date + '</td>';
            row += '<td>' + data.rows[i].company + '</td>';
            row += '<td>' + data.rows[i].location + '</td>';
            ...
            row += '</tr>';
        }
        $(row).appendTo('table.data');
    },
});
```

JSON:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "date": "Date",
        "company": "Company",
        "location": "Location",
        ...
    },
    "rows": [{
        "date": "09/18/2011",
        "company": "Company name",
        "location": "US",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if lumping all the rows into a string, turning it into a jQuery object and then appending it to the table is a good idea, assuming this can be done multiple times on the page to refresh the data.

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery templates - http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/ ?

Comment: I don't think it's good to propose using a plugin that is in beta and is subject to change for production reasons.

Comment: @Floyd "These documentation topics concern the jQuery Templates **plugin**". The OP stated they didn't want to use one.

Comment: @lolwut and JamWaffles: My bad. I did miss the mention of the plugins being out of scope.

Comment: [An answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7196384/575530) to another question suggests that your approach "to build the string first then add it all in one call" is indeed more performant than multiple adds.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than the `for` .. `in` syntax and the string-building, I would use the [`jQuery.each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'public.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var $tr =$('<tr>').addClass('header');
        $.each(data.headers, function(i,header){
            $tr.append($('<th>').append($('a').addClass('sort').attr('href','#').append($('span').text(header))));
        });
        $tr.appendTo('table.data');
        $.each(data.rows,function(i,row){
            $('<tr>').attr('id',i).
                append($('<td>').text(row.date)).
                append($('<td>').text(row.company)).
                append($('<td>').text(row.location)).appendTo('table.data');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using $.each instead of for...in? I was under the impression that $.each is more costly than for...in.

Comment: You're right. I did not know that. You could use jQuery rather than string building, but as your question is about the expensiveness, I guess your code is just fine... http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/6