# How create table or append from JSON format?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, html-table

After process a tiny search engine with ajax-jQuery, and functions in PHP, I've a Array JSON and I want process this for append rows in table exists but I get confused.

The JSON format from query mysql is OK, but I don't know how process data to generate table or append in my exists table.

I think that is applied each for taking each element of JSON but I can not think as.

**Note:** My JSON Code was generate to this this way

```
       ...........
       $jsonSearchResults = array();
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $jsonSearchResults[] =  array(
                        'clavemat' => $row['cve_mat'],
                        'tipomat' => $row['tipo_mat'],
                        'titulomat' => $row['titulo_mat'],
                        'autormat' => $row['autor_mat'],
                        'editmat' => $row['edit_mat'],
                        'success' => 'success'  
                    );
                }
         echo json_encode ($jsonSearchResults);
```

**Table HTML**

```
.........
<table class="busqueda">
<tr>
<th scope="col">Clave</th>
<th scope="col">Tipo</th>
<th scope="col">Título</th>
<th scope="col">Autor</th>
<th scope="col">Editorial</th>
</tr>
</table>
........
```

**JSON CODE**

```
[
{
"clavemat":"LICOELMCUS",
"tipomat":"Libro",
"titulomat":"Contabilidad",
"autormat":"Elias Flores",
"editmat":"McGraw Hill",
"success":"success"
},
{
"clavemat":"LICUDEMCNU",
"tipomat":"Libro",
"titulomat":"Curso java",
"autormat":"Deitel",
"editmat":"McGraw Hill",
"success":"success"
},
{
"clavemat":"REECMUMUNU",
"tipomat":"Revista",
"titulomat":"Eclipses",
"autormat":"Muy Interesante",
"editmat":"Muy interesante",
"success":"success"
},
{
"clavemat":"TEPLPLTENU",
"tipomat":"Tesis",
"titulomat":"Platanito Show",
"autormat":"Platanito",
"editmat":"Telehit",
"success":"success"
}
]
```

**AJAX.JQUERY FILE**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: dataSearch,
            success: function (response) {

                if (response[0].success == "success") {
                    alert("Si hay datos");
                } else {
                    alert("No hay datos");
                }

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7668413/1048572. It's easy.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with that code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
$.each(response, function (index, record) {
    var row = $("<tr />");
    $("<td />").text(record.clavemat).appendTo(row);
    $("<td />").text(record.tipomat).appendTo(row);
    $("<td />").text(record.titulomat).appendTo(row);
    $("<td />").text(record.autormat).appendTo(row);
    $("<td />").text(record.editmat).appendTo(row);

    row.appendTo("table.busqueda");
});
```

The above code appends rows to an existing table with class "busqueda".

Answer (score 2):

In your table you could add a `<tbody>` element as a container for the dynamic rows:

```
<table class="busqueda">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Clave</th>
      <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
      <th scope="col">Título</th>
      <th scope="col">Autor</th>
      <th scope="col">Editorial</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="dynamic_rows">
    <!-- Ajax results go here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then in the ajax success callback you would render the rows:

```
if (response[0].success == "success") {
  // Render dynamic rows here
  var $dynamic_rows = $('#dynamic_rows');

  // clear out old rows
  dynamic_rows.html('');

  ///////
  // You can use the row building code from Rafael's answer here
  // except append to $dynamic_rows

} else {
  alert("No hay datos");
}
```

Comment: You should not use innerHTML with <tbody> or <table> elements, IE is buggy as always.