# Value lost while RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app which is showing unexpected behavior while using `return view()` and `return RedirectToAction` with combination of Ajax. Let me show the relevant code first, then I will share replication steps of the problem.

This is my view `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model NoSql_MVC_Core.Models.Product.ProductInfo
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div class="container container-fluid">
<p>Total : @Model.Total</p>
<p>Skip : @Model.Skip</p>
<p>Limit : @Model.Limit</p>
<table id="products" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-dark">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>discountPercentage</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Thumbnail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if(Model!= null && Model.Products != null && Model.Products.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(var item in Model.Products)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                    <td>@item.Price</td>
                    <td>@item.DiscountPercentage</td>
                    <td>@item.Rating</td>
                    <td>@item.Stock</td>
                    <td>@item.Brand</td>
                    <td>@item.Category</td>
                    <td><img src="@item.Thumbnail" style="width:120px;height:80px"></td>
                </tr>
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9" class="text-center">No Records</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/scripts/products.js"></script>
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(ProductInfo productInfo)
        {
            return View(productInfo);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LoadProducts([FromBody] ProductInfo productInfo)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", productInfo);
        }
}
```

Here is my `product.js` code file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetProducts();
});

function GetProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "https://dummyjson.com/products",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (Result) {
            var productsInfo = {};
            if (Result) {
                productsInfo.total = Result.total;
                productsInfo.skip = Result.skip;
                productsInfo.limit = Result.limit;
                productsInfo.products = Result.products;
                LoadProducts(productsInfo);
            }
            else {

            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            if (e.status != 200) {
                alert("error " + e.status + ' : ' + e.statusText);
            }
        }
    });
}

function LoadProducts(param) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Home/LoadProducts",
        data: JSON.stringify(param),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        success: function (Result) {
            if (Result) {
            }
            else {
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            if (e.status == 200) {
            }
            if (e.status != 200) {
                alert("error " + e.status + ' : ' + e.statusText);
            }
        },
        complete: function (e) {
            
        }
    });
}
```

These are my model classes:

```
public class ProductInfo
{
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public int Skip { get; set; }
        public int Limit { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }
        public float DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
        public float Rating { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string[] Images { get; set; }
}
```

In my application, on page load, first js function `GetProducts()` is invoked within `document.ready` (refer to the `product.js` file). It's actually hitting a dummy API to get some data.

Once it get the data, it calls `LoadProducts()` method from the same js file.

Within `LoadProducts`, I am making an Ajax call to the action method `LoadProducts()` on my controller, and passing the data as post request body.

Now within the ASP.NET Core MVC action method, if I use `return view()`, then it does not refresh the page:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoadProducts([FromBody] ProductInfo productInfo)
{
    return View("Index", productInfo);
}
```

Is this approach is wrong, will it not reload the page with data?

If I use `return RedirectToAction`, then it does invoke the `index.cshtml` file, debugger moves to razor syntax but this time it lost data partially in view.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoadProducts([FromBody] ProductInfo productInfo)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", productInfo);
}
```

Here we can see jQuery Ajax has posted data to action method and now we will do `RedirectToAction` and

[image]

Once the control moved within Index, value for Limit, SKip And Total is there only for products it became as count zero. Product is a List of Type `Product` and its content lost while doing redirect to action.

[image]

Although the value of Limit, SKip and Total was there in Index action method but at view it get displayed as zero always

So the question is: if I use Ajax and transport data to action method than will it ignore to re-render the view despite calling the `return view()` statement

And if jQuery post to another method like we did here, Ajax posted to loadproducts and loadproducts invoke index with redirect to action statement, how does value get lost only for one property and view still not getting updated for other properties?

Is this approach incorrect? If yes, then what improvements can I make?

Comment: Why you need to call `LoadProducts` after you get the data from the API? Did you consider calling the dummy API in the `Index` method and populate Model and pass it to the view?

Comment: That i can do, directly calling api in c# code and render the view. But here have to use ajax ,

Comment: Then you should use data from dummy API to populate the view in AJAX only instead of calling LoadProducts. `Result` has the data from dummy API, you can use JQuery to load that data in the table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196238/populate-html-table-with-jquery

Comment: That has been done by another way, lets not focus on how to view data. Lets focus on question asked which are still unanswered, why value lost in RedirectToAction and Why return view() does not take affect here

Comment: you can not pass objects between redirections. You can use TempData though. Inside LoadProducts store productInfo in TempData. And inside Index method, try to retrieve it from TempData and pass it to the view. You don't need any parameter in tine Index method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492634/passing-tempdata-with-redirecttoaction

Comment: are you sure ? RedirectToAction(string? actionName, string? controllerName, object? routeValues, string? fragment); look different than this explanation

Comment: Yes.. I am sure... the `object` parameter in RedirectToAction is for the route values. Not for sending the entire model object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-controller-redirecttoaction(system-string-system-string-system-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render a view from AJAX directly. In your case, I think you can use partial view to achieve, Please refer to this demo.

I create two partial views:

**_PartialForm.csthml**

```
@model ProductInfo

@if (Model != null && Model.Products != null && Model.Products.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td>@item.Description</td>
            <td>@item.Price</td>
            <td>@item.DiscountPercentage</td>
            <td>@item.Rating</td>
            <td>@item.Stock</td>
            <td>@item.Brand</td>
            <td>@item.Category</td>
            <td><img src="@item.Thumbnail" style="width:120px;height:80px"></td>
        </tr>
    }
}
else
{
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9" class="text-center">No Records</td>
    </tr>
}
```

**_PartialHead.cshtml**

```
@model ProductInfo


@if (Model != null)
{
    <p>Total : @Model.Total</p>
    <p>Skip : @Model.Skip</p>
    <p>Limit : @Model.Limit</p>
}
else
{
    <p>Total : null</p>
    <p>Skip : null</p>
    <p>Limit : null</p>
}
```

**Then Change your Index view like:**

```
<div class="container container-fluid">

    <div id="partialViewHeader">       
    </div>
    
    <table id="products" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-dark">
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>discountPercentage</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Thumbnail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="partialViewForm">           
                      
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Controller/Action**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LoadProductsHead([FromBody] ProductInfo productInfo)
        {
            return PartialView("_PartialHead", productInfo);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LoadProductsFrom([FromBody] ProductInfo productInfo)
        {
            return PartialView("_PartialForm", productInfo);
        }
```

**Finally, In JavaScript code, I write will send two ajax to above actions and return partial view to the Index View.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            GetProducts();
        });

        function GetProducts() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "https://dummyjson.com/products",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (Result) {
                    var productsInfo = {};
                    if (Result) {
                        productsInfo.total = Result.total;
                        productsInfo.skip = Result.skip;
                        productsInfo.limit = Result.limit;
                        productsInfo.products = Result.products;
                        LoadProductsHead(productsInfo);
                        LoadProductsForm(productsInfo);
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    if (e.status != 200) {
                        alert("error " + e.status + ' : ' + e.statusText);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function LoadProductsHead(param) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Test/LoadProductsHead",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: false,
                success: function (Result) {
                    if (Result) {
                        $('#partialViewHeader').html(Result)
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    if (e.status == 200) {
                    }
                    if (e.status != 200) {
                        alert("error " + e.status + ' : ' + e.statusText);
                    }
                },
                complete: function (e) {

                }
            });
        }

        function LoadProductsForm(param) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Test/LoadProductsFrom",
                data: JSON.stringify(param),
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: false,
                success: function (Result) {
                    if (Result) {
                        $('#partialViewForm').html(Result)
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    if (e.status == 200) {
                    }
                    if (e.status != 200) {
                        alert("error " + e.status + ' : ' + e.statusText);
                    }
                },
                complete: function (e) {

                }
            });
        }
```

**gif demo**

[image]

Hope this answer can give you some help.

Comment: Thanks. Got to know another way in asp.net mvc. Any other way other than returning html markup from controller to js file ?